# Foundation 6 change.zf.slider event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

this my first time posting, so here goes...

For the life of me, I cannot get the

```
$("[data-slider]").on('change.zf.slider', function(){});
```

event to fire. I've tried using the **id** of the element as well

```
$("#slider").on('change.zf.slider', function(){});
```

but still nothing.

I've searched through google and stack overflow with all possible combinations and variations of this specific problem that came to mind, but no help.

I've gone through the Foundation 6 documentation on this class and that is where I found the event name. But testing it, didn't work.

This is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).foundation();
   });
   $("[data-slider]").on('change.zf.slider', function() {
     console.log("slider!");
   });
</script>
```

This is the HTML for the element itself:

```
<div id="slider" class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="10">
  <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="val"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
</div>
```

and these are the includes (they were at the time of posting):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.slider.js"></script>
```

After posting I remembered the documentation mentioning the need of adding the foundation.core.js, foundation.util.motion.js, foundation.util.keybaord.js, foundation.util.triggers.js and foundation.util.touch.js and then it started throwing the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined
```

so I searched that, and found a suggestion to add the foundation.util.mediaQuery.js which supposedly has a co-dependency with the core.js, so the includes look as follows.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.util.motion.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.util.triggers.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.util.keyboard.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.util.touch.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.slider.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.core.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.1/plugins/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js"></script>
```

but that broke the foundation functionality, now the off-canvas menu doesn't open either and no errors what-so-ever...

Comment: Ok, so I just thought I'd test the other event that sliders are supposed to broadcast, the "moved.zf.slider" event, and this works perfectly.

Comment: I've tried the above in a fiddle and I've been unable to get it working. It seems that the event is redundant. The docs mention a `data-changed-delay` attribute and even setting that to 0 has no effect. The default is 500 milliseconds, so the event should fire 500 milliseconds after the slider has stopped moving, which it isn't. I can confirm that the `moved.zf.slider` event works as expected.

Comment: Ok, great, so it isn't just me :P
Maybe this event is used for something entirely else, for example, if the appearance or attributes of the slider change, not the slider value?

Comment: Possibly. The docs aren't helpful at all. The description is way too vague for my liking. It definitely needs more investigation.

Comment: When you are mentioning `foundation.min.js` you **need not** mention any other `js` file(s) to get the plugins working **except** for any version of `jquery.min.js` . Include the `jquery.min.js` file first and then include the reference for `foundation.min.js` file. That's all you need to start with.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but you need to use changed.zf.slider rather than change.zf.slider (note the 'd'). So this should work for you:

```
$("#containerID").on('change changed.zf.slider', function(){});
```

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html